# InfluxDB database Replication

Tags: influxdb

we are using Telegraf, Influxdb and Grafana for Monitoring our environment. We have two datacenters dc1 and dc2. Each datacenter has one pod of Influxdb running. we want some approach to replicate the data between two influxdb instances running across two datacenters. So, if dc1 goes down we can have the data of both datacenters(dc1 and dc2) in dc2. We are using opensource Influxdb so can anyone please suggest some approaches to achieve this?

Tried to follow Replication during ingest approach where we configure two influxdb urls of both datacenters in telegraf.conf as per this https://www.influxdata.com/blog/multiple-data-center-replication-influxdb/ documentation but, what if one of the influxdb is down? and also after it's recovery both influxdb will have different data so, we do not want to follow this approach.

Comment: As far as i know proper replication works only in Enterprise version of InfluxDB

Comment: Hi @Nikolay Thanks for the response can we use Influxdb Relay for the Influxdb replication in Opensource version?

Comment: I am not an expert, but i believe yes, you can use InfluxDB Relay with Opensource.